# soundcloud recent plays api

Tags: api, soundcloud

When you connect your soundcloud to facebook it can post the tracks you listen to in your newsfeed as you listen to them.

Are the recently played tracks of a user accessible through the public api?

Answer (score 1):

No, this information is not available through the public API. All public API endpoints are [documented here](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference).